# Laravel 5 can't return or call table result from the database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have been trying to get this to work for several days off and on now, and my mind is most likely just missing some minute detail. I cannot get a database query to call from my controller to pass it into the view. Any help as to why this isn't passing the data (or contacting the database for that matter) would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

This is my ViewAppController.php:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager;
class ViewAppController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
            $test = DB::table('test')->select('something');
            return view('viewapp')->with('test', $test);
    }
}
```

This is my view:

```
{{ $test }}
```

Command in-line on mysql "select something from test;" prints out what it needs to, but it just doesn't work while inside of the php files

```
+---------------------------+
| something                 |
+---------------------------+
| Hello world - Root insert |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

.env file:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=rawrhidden

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=applyta
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password
...
```

database.php:
the default is set to mysql

```
'mysql' => [
  'driver'    => 'mysql',
  'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
  'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', ''),
  'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
  'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
  'charset'   => 'utf8',
  'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
  'prefix'    => '',
  'strict'    => false,
 ],
```

Even running straight up database calls in the view (using mysql php commands, which I was trying as a last second bandaid) doesn't work. I feel like Laravel is blocking my database calls.

Comment: I haven't tried used `getenv` for Laravel `.env` values, but there's a helper function meant to be used that is simply `env` - http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers#miscellaneous

Comment: We had it setup that way originally, and it still did not work. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting

```
use DB;
```

underneath the

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
public function index()
{
        $test = DB::table('test')->get();
        return view('viewapp')->with('test', $test);
}
```

And then in your view, you would do this.

```
@foreach ($test as $item)
    {{ $item }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Does the passing of the $test variable work if it's inside of <?php ?>  rather than using the laravel setup of {{ }} ?

Comment: I think it will, but why would you use that? Your view supports blade templating system which is very powerful. I will update my code to add a foreach loop for you.

Comment: I tried it your way in the view controller as well as the view, but to no avail. Although your DB call isn't storing anything, so (I tried yours originally) I used the command $test = DB::table('test')->select('something')->get(); and still had nothing return to the view. I'm still getting a blank page. I also updated my database.php file to how it was originally and updated the OP

Comment: DB::table is not for storing, it's only for retrieving. Your database should already contain data.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I mean how are you supposed to pass the retrieved data back to the view if it's not being stored in a variable after you call it out?

Comment: You are already passing the $test variable, it's in your code. I updated my code, you are already calling all the fields from the table "test" by calling `DB::table('test')` now you have to append `get()` to be able to get the result and pass it to your `$test` variable.

Comment: It still doesn't work... We can get a normal .php file to do the basic mysql call, but when we try to implement Laravel's DB calls and controllers, it doesn't work. I guess I have no idea what I'm doing..

Comment: Try going here https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals this is a video tutorial to get you started with laravel 5